# Chi "ha abbandonato" le sabbie in questo passaggio?

Tags: meaning

C'è un passaggio [tratto](https://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Il_fu_Mattia_Pascal/5) da *Il fu Mattia Pascal* da Luigi Pirandello:

> La vista del mare mi faceva cadere in uno sgomento attonito, che diveniva man mano oppressione intollerabile. Sedevo su la spiaggia e m’impedivo di guardarlo, abbassando il capo: ma ne sentivo per tutta la riviera il fragorìo, mentre lentamente, lentamente, mi lasciavo scivolar di tra le dita la sabbia densa e greve, mormorando:
>
> — Così, sempre, fino alla morte, senz’alcun mutamento, mai...
>
> L’immobilità della condizione di quella mia esistenza mi suggeriva allora pensieri sùbiti, strani, quasi lampi di follia. Balzavo in piedi, come per scuotermela d’addosso, e mi mettevo a passeggiare lungo la riva; ma vedevo allora il mare mandar senza requie, là, alla sponda, le sue stracche ondate sonnolente; *vedevo quelle sabbie lì abbandonate*; gridavo con rabbia, scotendo le pugna: — Ma perchè? ma perchè?

Ho una domanda per voi, se non vi dispiace. *Abbandonate* da chi? Dalla gente, dagli uomini del paese? Oppure dalle ondate? Forse è ovvio per chi parla italiano da madrelingua... Grazie!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Abbandonato](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/abbandonato) è anche usato come aggettivo; non è solo il participio passato di “abbandonare”.

Non è specificato, né lasciato intendere implicitamente, *chi* abbia abbandonato le sabbie. Non importa: stanno lì, lasciate a sé stesse, nessuno ci fa niente, nessuno se ne cura.

Answer (score 4):

Al contesto da te citato si adatta ad [abbandonate](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/abbandonato/) la seguente accezione:

> **abbandonato** agg. [part. pass. di abbandonare]. – **1. Lasciato definitivamente, e in partic. lasciato senza cure, senza assistenza,
>   senza protezione**, conforme ai varî sign. del verbo: casa, città a.,
>   senza più abitanti, deserta; terreno a., lasciato incolto; bambini a.,
>   infanzia a., dai genitori.

che significa, indipendentemente dal soggetto, che le sabbie erano solitarie, non frequentate da nessuno, sempre uguali, portate dal mare con il suo incessante moto ondoso.

Tutto sta a sottolineare l'immutabilità della situazione rimarcata dal passaggio:

> — Così, sempre, fino alla morte, senz’alcun mutamento, mai...